# How to get an attribute computed on the attributes of collection of views

Tags: ember.js

I have a view object like this:

```
App.ThingView = Ember.View.extend({
    things: App.thingsController,
    weightBinding: 'content.weight',
    unitConversionFactorBinding: 'App.thingsController.unitConversionFactor',

    percentWeight: function() {
        var weight = this.getPath('content.weight');
        var totalWeight = this.getPath('things.totalWeight');
        return (weight / totalWeight) * 100;
    }.property('content.weight', 'things.totalWeight'),

    weightUnits: function() {
        var weight = this.getPath('content.weight');
        var unitConversionFactor = this.get('unitConversionFactor');
        return weight * unitConversionFactor;
    }.property('content.weigth', 'unitConversionFactor'),

});
```

And this view is used to iterate over a controller array  like so:

```
{{#each App.thingsController tagName="ul"}}
    {{#view App.ThingView contentBinding="this"}}
            {{weight}} - {{percentWeight}}  % - {{weightUnits}}
            {{#view deleteButton}}Delete{{/view}}
    {{/view}}
{{/each}}
```

I would like to display to total for weigthUnits, basically to iterate over the views rendered by the #each helper and add them. Is this possible? Or do I need to revert to putting all this computed properties logic in the models (in order to access aggregate computations from the controller)? I've set up a jsfiddle here: 
http://jsfiddle.net/sohara/MuwDd/19/

Answer (score 0):

How about this: http://jsfiddle.net/tomwhatmore/fqR8W/1/

In a hurry right now, but I think that js fiddle covers it? Moved the weightUnit logic to the model as you mentioned.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but for a couple of reasons I need to keep that logic out of the model. One is that there are other dependencies in my computed functions that are not in this simplified example, but that depend on the controller and other objects in the system. The other is that generally a model object should not know about the state of the controller that it 'belongs to'... an mvc violation, I would think.

Comment: I update the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sohara/MuwDd/52/ and tried using an observer on the view object to update a property on the controller... probably an antipattern, but I don't see how I can avoid an antipattern in this case... oh well.

Comment: Ah, didn't see your response. I thought it might be missing something in simplification, ending up with the model relying on the controller would have been pretty bad. Your solution does look a little ant pattern-y but if it works then that's better than nothing I suppose.

Comment: In the end I created an intermediary object between the controller and the model to hold the computed property functions that I need. I think in this case it was the right way to go, it keeps the logical separation I needed between controllers and views. Basically it is an ObjectProxy, similar to an array proxy.